# JIRA REST API using OAuth-Restricting access to a single project only

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Let's say an admin user has several projects under his JIRA instance. He needs to give access ( To a third party application )to a single project in JIRA. Can this be achieved via REST API using OAuth?

What I need is, in my web application, user is asked to configure an existing JIRA project. Then he can specify the project name and then allow the application to access only the specified project without accessing any other projects.

I tried to achieve this using Application Links as in https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication

But still in step 1, I can't restrict access to a single project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should play with the JIRA permissions. If every project is readable by the group `jira-users`, then you'll have to move everybody to a new group (eg. `employees`), except the  given service user. Then, let that user only into that one project.

We have ~500 projects in one of our instances by now, so we have a xyz-employees group, and different groups for contractors and consultants, per company. Then, those groups are assigned only to the projects they need access to. This way, they won't even see the other projects, except if there is a security schema that depends on a customfield.

Comment: Thank u. It seems I'll have to add a group and manage this. I was wondering whether I can do it when I give OAuth access rather than creating a separate group.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth is used for authentication. 
Regarding your problem, so far there is not option to create project using Jira REST API. [See latest doc.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/)

There might be some options, using add-ons or developing your own add-on, as mentioned [here.](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54168/can-we-create-projects-in-jira-using-rest-api-calls)

Comment: Hi thanks, I don't have the problem of creating a project as of now, but what I need is to give access to an existing project (while restricting user to only that project)